# Who assigns identifiers to the homescreen widget instances?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-launcher, android-appwidget

Is the identifier (which is an `Integer`) given by the launcher or the Android framework? The reason I'm asking this is that so I know where to look (or file a bug-report if necessary.)

I have a few home screen widgets that I've been developing. Each of these have a settings-activity and store store their configuration data in individual preference files identified by INSTANCE_ID.xml. This works perfectly but this morning when I restarted my phone into safe mode and then rebooted it normally, none of the widgets worked because they were unable to open their XML preference files since the widgets all have new identifiers. This seems like incorrect behaviour to me. I'm using a custom launcher called Nova and I'm trying to figure out why this is happening?

Comment: Safe mode? I wonder how did you do that. AFAIK you can restore an Android device to factory settings, but safe mode? Is it a custom ROM?

Comment: Also happens on stock based KitKat ROM on LG G3